# How to open the MenuInflater with a button on Screen?

Tags: android, button, view, menu

Is there any way to open the MenuInflater using the onClick call?

if you use:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
```

I'm not able to initialize the Menu.

```
Menu menu = new Menu()
inflater.inflate(R.menu.picture_menu, menu);
```

And I believe there is no way to call this

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.picture_menu, menu);
}
```

if not through the MENU BUTTON;

Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [Activity.openOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29) in your onClick()

Comment: Glad it helped! Please mark the answer as correct to close this question.